# Is there a messenger that can appear offline to some contacts and online to other contacts?

Tags: software-recommendation, instant-messaging

I am looking for a messenger which lets me choose who I want to appear online to and who I want to appear offline to (like Windows Live Messenger in Windows).

Is there any thing that could do the job in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on the particular service you are connecting to, since Linux clients have no control over what a sever does once it's told it you're online. Some (Facebook chat for example), simply don't provide the option to selectively appear as online or offline - and there's nothing that any client (whether running on Linux or Windows) can do about it.

If you're saying that there's a specific feature of the Windows Live service which allows this, then I don't know which (if any) Linux clients support it. But if it's not available in either Pidgin or Empathy (which I don't believe it is) then I strongly doubt it will be available in any others.

Comment: I vaguely remember that Yahoo Messenger had this option, maybe still has.